# Rock Paper Scissors in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to build code where the user is prompted for "rock", "paper", or "scissors", and then that is compared with a random computer choice.  The computer's choice is deemed by a random value between 0 and 1. Our compare function passes through both of these choices and compares their value to return an output, telling which hand signal wins. I am getting a syntax error but cannot seem to figure out what I'm missing.

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    } else(choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            return "scissors wins";
        } else {
            return "rock wins";
        }
    }
}

console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Comment: "I am getting a syntax error" — What is the error message? What line does it refer to?

Comment: this is the exact message: " SyntaxError: missing  before statement"

Comment: Else's don't have conditions: `else (choice1 === "scissors")`

Comment: Add Lizard and Spock as well. Visit: http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else (choice1 === "scissors") {` is the issue. Either do an `else if (...) {` or an `else {`
.

By the way, the syntax error tells you the exact error. In the Chrome developer tools, I only had to click on the error in the console to see the line.

Comment: Ok thank you, that makes sense now.  I am using codeacademy, and it doesn't seem to specify the location of the error.

Answer (score 6):

You have a condition for your `else` statement. Either remove it or add the `if`.

```
} else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
  if (choice2 === "paper") {
    return "scissors wins";
  } else {
    return "rock wins";
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that seemed to fix it. That also makes sense to me now

Answer (score 0):

```
else (choice1 === "scissors") {
```

is an illegal statment.

```
else if
```

expects a conditional.

```
else
```

should not have one.